# Deploying and Accessing Database Inside Docker Container

Tags: node.js, docker, mariadb

I'm trying to deploy a docker container that holds a MariaDB. I want this on the cloud and be able to store and retrieve data from it.

I understand how to setup the container and install MariaDB on it, but is what I'm trying to achieve in the end possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Comment: @Matt any recommendations as to how I should go about this?

Comment: It's a very general question, unless you can add more specifics you just need someone to host your container. https://www.google.com/search?q=docker+hosting